# Should this be migrated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, migration, off-topic

I was reviewing a rather long question today and I'm not sure if it should be migrated from Stack Overflow to a more appropriate Stack Exchange site or closed for some reason.

The post in question:

> [Approach to submitting forms from a multi-platform native/hybrid app with unstable internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359476/approach-to-submitting-forms-from-a-multi-platform-native-hybrid-app-with-unstab)

Is this the type of question that could perhaps be migrated to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)? I've been checking the [faq](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) and I'm really not sure. Or is it the case that this question is appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Comment: There is an overlap between Programmers and Stack Overflow - some questions could belong to both/either.

Comment: It's more likely to take a pounding on SO these days though, simply because it's long. (Which arguably is a shame.)

Comment: It does seem to be more of a design question which would be definitely on topic for Programmers.

Comment: @ChrisF for SO moderators! that way, you could use your left hand at SO to pass questions like this to your right hand at Programmers and vice versa

Comment: I feel that this question would get the attention it deserves on Programmers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've migrated it (now I can) as it hasn't been answered on Stack Overflow.

Hopefully it will get an answer on Programmers.